# Is there a way to find if someone your server in Discord belongs to a particular server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I was looking for a way if you can find all the members from a particular server in discord to let's say remove them from your server as they can be from your opponents' server lurking around. If there is a way I want to create a discord bot for it. Any help related to it will be appreciated.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do this. Discord bots/clients can only tell which servers the bot/client is in, but no which servers the members of a guild are in.

Comment: @JacobLee Thank You very much for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, but this would require that the user authorizes your application. It would work something like this:

1. Your bot has some sort of webserver listening
2. Your bot gives them a link
3. They click the link, discord asks them to authorize your bot
4. Discord redirects them to your webserver with a token in the parameters
5. Using that token, you can access info such as what guilds they are in.

This is easiest if you already have a bot dashboard, but can still be achieved without one (though you still need a webserver to listen for the callback).

If you have a quart webserver (which is how I would recommend doing it) then take a look at this: https://github.com/jnawk/Quart-Discord

Edit: Also note that, if your bot is in this other guild, you can do a simple check, like this:

```py
g = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
await g.chunk()
if member in g.members:
    # ban them
```